# I didn't understand this part of transposition

Tags: least-squares

[image: Let β = (β0, β1, . . . , βp) be the (p + 1)-vector of coefficients. The vector of predicted values (f (x1), . . . , f (xn))T can be written as Xβ.]
Let β = (β0, β1, . . . , βp) be the (p + 1)-vector of coefficients.
The vector of predicted values (f (x1), . . . , f (xn))T can be written as
Xβ.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$.  So the expression is equivalent to

$$ =\mathbf{y}^T \mathbf{y}-(\beta^T \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{y})^T-\beta^T \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{y}+\beta^T \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X} \beta $$

$$ =\mathbf{y}^T \mathbf{y}-2\beta^T \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{y}+\beta^T \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X} \beta $$

Comment: is −(β^TX^Ty)^T = -β^TX^Ty ??

Comment: No -- the formula in that comment doesn't usually even make sense according to the rules of matrix multiplication, because the dimensions won't match.  Do the calculation with $2\times 2$ matrices so you can see what's going on.

Comment: so why −(β^TX^Ty)^T−β^TX^Ty = -2β^TX^Ty ?????

Comment: Because all three terms--the two on the left and the one on the right--are numbers.  Again, this becomes intuitive and obvious when you write it out in small dimensions.

Comment: β^TX^Ty is a number so −(β^TX^Ty)^T = −(β^TX^Ty) and then -(β^TX^Ty)^T−β^TX^Ty = -2β^TX^Ty. is that correct ??

Comment: $(\beta^T \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{y})^T$ is a scalar.  It doesn't matter it if it is transposed or not, it remains a scalar.  Since it is a scalar, we can group the two like terms.

Comment: **Please read the first line of this answer.**  It gives the correct formula; there's no reason to keep quoting an erroneous formula.

Comment: Thank you Demetri and whuber for your help!